# Why does the `--list` option to `kubectl auth can-i` display the same permissions for any user provided with `--as` option?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to display the allowed permissions for users and service accounts in my Kubernetes cluster. To achive this, I use the `kubectl auth can-i --list --namespace=default --as=<user>` command.

However, for any user, except my current `docker-desktop` user, it displays the same set of permissions:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i --list --namespace=default --as='foo'
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names   Verbs
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                  []               [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                  []               [create]
                                                [/api/*]            []               [get]
                                                [/api]              []               [get]
                                                [/apis/*]           []               [get]
                                                [/apis]             []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]          []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]          []               [get]
                                                [/openapi/*]        []               [get]
                                                [/openapi]          []               [get]
                                                [/version/]         []               [get]
                                                [/version/]         []               [get]
                                                [/version]          []               [get]
                                                [/version]          []               [get]


$ kubectl auth can-i --list --namespace=default --as='bar'
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names   Verbs
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                  []               [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                  []               [create]
                                                [/api/*]            []               [get]
                                                [/api]              []               [get]
                                                [/apis/*]           []               [get]
                                                [/apis]             []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]          []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]          []               [get]
                                                [/openapi/*]        []               [get]
                                                [/openapi]          []               [get]
                                                [/version/]         []               [get]
                                                [/version/]         []               [get]
                                                [/version]          []               [get]
                                                [/version]          []               [get]
```

This is true both for existing service accounts, specified as `system:serviceaccount:<namespace>:<serviceaccount>` as well as non-existing user accounts, like `foo` and `bar` (see above).

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird caveat of using this command.It does not error out but fallback to show same permission for nonexistent user/service accounts and existing service accounts/users which does not have any permission.